# c# linq graph database based path search

Tags: c#, sql, linq, security, design-patterns

Situation example (oriented cyclic graph with some edge restrictions):

4 different entity Types (**A**, **B**, **C**, **D**), 7 Relations (directed graph edges: **A** <-> **B**, **A** -> **D**, **B** -> **D**, **B** <-> **C**, **C** -> **D**). Graph dynamically changes.
The only graph function is to list all objects of one type, where path exists from selected vertices.

### [image: example graph relations illustration]

I'm looking for design pattern, which can be used in realtime queries on (MS) SQL (best using c# linq). I know some base algorithms for path search in graphs, but I can't imagine performance on database.
Basically it's used for security purposes. I read about some interesting security access patterns (lattice-based access control), but I'm not sure about solution and mainly about performance (1kk object of each of 15 entity types per user).

Any literature, thesis, ideas, blogs are welcomed.

Comment: How many edges do you expect to have in your database?  I am curious because to use LINQ to do the search, I think, is going to require you to pull all edges down from your db.  I suppose you could just pull all the edges that start from your selected nodes in one query and then pull all the edges that start from destination nodes of your first query in your second query, etc...   Either way, if you have a lot of edges doing this with LINQ could be costly.  I have done something similar (my situation was much easier because I was dealing with trees) using a recursive query.

Comment: I don't think it would be sufficient. Recursive query itself is too expensive. I was thinking about NoSQL or other no relation based databases. But I don't have any chance to change existing database. So only solution using no-relation database, would be somehow to be connected to MSSQL.

Comment: Have you considered representing your Adjacency matrix as XML and persisting it in an XML column? This should allow you to keep using SQL Server and profit from its XML querying capabilities.